# How can someone follow a tag before it existed

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-watching

Yesterday, I created the [user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface) tag on MSO and immediately after the create was created, when the tag description popped up, I noticed that it already had 2 followers

[image: Screen shot showing 2 followers for a newly created tag]

How is this possible?  Is this related to users of MSO following the tag before the MSO/MSE split, or is there something else at work here?

Does this also occur for tags that get cleaned up and later get recreated?  Will the follower of that tag still follow the new occurrence of that tag?

Comment: Probably, the tag was already created. But it was deleted when it was removed. The "extra" information was still somewhere on the server.

Comment: My initial thought was either the above (tag already existed previously and had 2 followers when it was deleted), or there might be some bots that auto follow tags.